# Image on Plane disappears at specific position

Tags: texturing, uv, eevee-render-engine

I'm having a very strange situation here. I have an Image imported as a plane in 2.8, separated it and it's working fine, but the second I am getting the images close to where I want them to be they disappear and I am left with blank planes.

At first I thought it was due to the light, but using a light point outside of the model doesn't make this mess.

From image 2 to 3 I haven't changed anything at all, but the position of the planes on the X-axis and as long as I am not doing this inside of the corridor I have made this doesn't influent the texture at all, it really just happens in that corridor. Absolutely no clue, I am thankful for any thoughts on this one.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using cycles?

Comment: Works fine in Cycles, but not in Eevee.

Answer (score 2):

Hi was having a similar problem. I resolved my issue by: material properties > settings > blend mode then changing the blend mode to alpha clip

Hope this helps!

Comment: That fixed it for me, thank you.